# how to set height of edit text in dialog in android for multiple screen?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am showing dialog with edittext. I want to ask how can set the height of the dialog. I have used  et_input.setHeight(100); but this accepts value in pixel which will be phone dependent.Is there any common way to achieve this.

Following is the code:

```
public String inputPopUp(Context context)
{
    inputBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    final EditText et_input=new EditText(context);
    et_input.setHint("Enter Description");
    et_input.setHeight(100);
    inputBuilder.setView(et_input);
    inputBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mealDesc=et_input.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    inputBuilder.show();
    return mealDesc;

}
```

Comment: Add some .xml Code for better understand .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define dimension in your app's dimens.xml file. dimens.xml would be different according to different device sizes. Read more about this : [Dimensions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

After doing this, change your code as below :

```
et_input.setHeight(MainActivity.this.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an android default value that you will use in the xml file like this : `layout_height="?listPreferredItemHeight"` and then it will adapt automatically to the screen size. Or you can define several dimens.xml in values-hdpi, values-mdpi, ... You will add a key like `<dimen name="edittext_height">30dp</dimen>` and change it's value in each folder. But the second solution requires more work and is not very stable...